# MySQL project design - conditionally select from one table based on rows from another select query

Tags: mysql, join, project

I have 2 tables in a MySQL database that are regularly appended with new data.  One is a list of rental properties and their characteristics eg 2 bed, 2 bath, location, rental price etc. The second table is a list of properties currently for sale.  From the rental table I can determine the average rent a particular type of property is getting in a particular location using the query:

```
SELECT bed, bath, type, suburb, postcode, AVG(price)
FROM rent_suburbs
GROUP BY bed, bath, type, suburb, postcode
```

I want to be able to select properties from the buy_items table where a user defined percentage of the sale price is less than the average rental price for a property matching the type and location.

I am trying trying to fix code below that someone suggested but I'm stuck.

```
select listing, bed, bath, type, address, postcode, state, price
from 
   buy_items
where (price*.0014) < avg(price) from 
select 
    bed, bath, type, suburb, postcode, avg(price)
from
    rent_items
group by bed , bath , type , suburb , postcode
/* and bed, bath, type, suburb and postcode match the buy_items property ????
```

I'm new so any help is appreciated.  Thanks

Table structure is as follows:

```
buy_items

buy_items_id2   int(11)
car         int(11)
price   int(11)
listing varchar(12)
bed         int(11)
bath    int(11)
suburb  varchar(25)
state   int(11)
scrapedate  int(11)
address varchar(45)
type    varchar(25)
postcode    int(11)
```

and

```
rent_items

rent_items_id2  int(11)
car         int(11)
price   int(11)
listing int(11)
bed         int(11)
bath    int(11)
suburb  varchar(25)
state   varchar(5)
scrapedate  int(11)
address varchar(45)
type    varchar(25)
postcode    int(11)
```

Comment: `WHERE avg(price) BETWEEN …` …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
   select listing, b.bed, bath, type, address, postcode, state, price
    from 
       buy_items b
    join (
    SELECT bed, bath, type, suburb, postcode, AVG(price) as avg_price
    FROM rent_suburbs
    GROUP BY bed, bath, type, suburb, postcode ) a
    on a.bed=b.bed and a.bath=b.bath and a.suburb=b.suburb and a.postcode=b.postcode
    where (b.price*.0014) < a.avg_price;
```

Comment: Im getting an error and cant seem to see what it is from MySQL Workbench - it just repeats the query in the action output.

Comment: could you post the structure of your tables?

Comment: I just worked out how to find what the error is: 'Error Code: 1052. Column 'bed' in field list is ambiguous'

Comment: Do the columns in a and b have to have different names or can I refer to them as but_items.bed to avoid ambiguity?